# surjectivity of a linear transformation and spanning

Tags: analysis, mathematical-physics

Okay, we have that $\{|a_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^n$ is a set of vectors spanning a vector space $V$. Also, $T\in L(V,W)$ is surjective, where $L(V,W)$ is the set of linear transformations (functionals) from $V$ to $W$.

I need to show that, given the above, $\{T$ $|a_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^n$ spans $W$.

And I don't know where to start.

Comment: Instead of < and > use \langle and \rangle.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still pretty new to LaTeX.

Comment: Do you really mean $\infty$, and not $n$, as the upper limit in the set of images?

Comment: No, its $n$, not $\infty$. Good catch! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Every $w\in W$ is the image under $T$ of some $v\in V$, and $v=\sum_{k=1}^nc_k|a_k\rangle$ for some constants $c_k$, $k=1,\dots,n$, so $w=Tv=T\sum_{k=1}^nc_k|a_k\rangle=\;?$